# CSS trends with naming class and id with dash underscore?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been using dashes as a separator for css Class and ID names:

```
.about-us
.car-pricing-guide
```

I've seen sites use multiple underscores `__`

```
.home__content
```

Also, I've seen 2 dashes

```
.hero--title
```

I know it's a matter of preference but can someone point to articles or the though process for these kind of patterns? Is there a move towards a particular convention or is there a popular set of convention people seem to agree/follow?

Comment: Two dashes is pretty unusual, can't say I've ever seen that. But ya, hyphens are probably the most popular.

Comment: This is the BEM convention(Block element modifier). __ represents the element and -- represents the modifier. You can refer this url for better understanding.  https://en.bem.info/method/naming-convention/

Comment: @NikhileshKV, BEM is a good reference

Comment: @claudios Yeah.It makes the code modular. I use it often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The double underscore follows the BEM methodology. It is basically a way of naming classes so that later it becomes easy for the user to understand.

**The guiding principle behind BEM seems to be "when designing a page, think in terms of reusable widgets". Which is pretty much the standard way you should be writing your semantic HTML.**

Learn more about BEM here: [BEM methoodology](https://en.bem.info/method/key-concepts/)

Comment: errr in the page there is written nothing about double underscore..! It is better explained here! https://en.bem.info/method/naming-convention/

Comment: Well you are expected to browse through a couple of pages on your own

Comment: @MarkWuji You're just referencing the same stuff... I think it's smart to read the from the start, i.e. the key concepts fist.! ;)

Answer (score 10):

I'm a huge advocate for using hyphens and it does seem to be more conventional. Long long ago some browsers didn't support underscores in class names and IDs, so hyphens were the preferred/standardized method. Even looking at CSS you see hyphens everywhere for things like `border-color`, so why not stick to the trend?

Hyphens also allow you to take advantage of things like the `|=` attribute. It lets you do nifty things like this:

```
span[class|="uppercase"] { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Which results in both

```
<h1 class="uppercase-header">The Three Little Pigs</h1>
```

and

```
<h2 class="uppercase-subheader">Chapter 1</h2>
```

both getting the style `text-transform: uppercase;`

Now, I've never actually *used* this selector... but if I need to, my code is ready!

If you're still not a believer in hyphens, here are some more great examples as to why they're a great standard to stick to: http://jasonbuckboyer.com/playground/use-hyphens-in-css/

Answer (score 6):

Let me add that an underscore does not separate a line into words. So you can (at least in Windows) double-click `some_selector`, and it will be selected, but to copy `some-selector` you will have to select it manually. Underscores save time when you have to copy a lot.

(Update: I should note, however, that an IDE will probably select a full css selector for you no matter what your word separator is).