# The reason to use "-" instead of "_" in the HTML class and id attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

why do people use **" - "** between their words instead of **" _ "** for example `class ="btn-submit"`, isn't this inefficient? if you use **"_"** by double-clicking it will select the **whole class name** instead of only **one side** so copying and using it in CSS or javascript will be easier.
double click on each of these below to see the difference

```
class ="btn-submit"

class ="btn_submit"
```

so there is any **specific reason** to do it that way or it's just something that is people using by **bad habit.**

Comment: half related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811509/why-hyphen-separated-class-names-are-widely-used-in-css or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710166/css-trends-with-naming-class-and-id-with-dash-underscore/36710323

Comment: I suspect that people who do that all the time don't think it's a bad habit.